# Trying to update mcrypt on yosemite

Tags: php, mcrypt, osx-yosemite

I went through the steps at [updating mcrypt on yosemite](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite-development-server/)

And when I went to run

```
sudo make install
```

and this is what came back

```
Tariks-Mac-mini:mcrypt tam3$ sudo make install
Installing shared extensions:     /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/
```

Why is it sharing extensions to MAMP? I have set my bash_profile to /usr/bin/php

How do I get everything pointing to the native php?

BTW, I have tried:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/bin/php
```

Comment: OK, I went into /etc/php.ini and changed directory from /usr/local/bin/php to /usr/bin/php followed by re-doing the steps after /usr/bin/phpize and it is now pointing to /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/

Comment: I just tried php -v and which php and it's back to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php - WTF?

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem installing Mcrypt with following commands in the site you mentioned and finally I could solve the problem after installing Command Line Tools for OS X 10.9 for Xcode 6.1.1 GM Seed which you can download form Downloads for Apple Developers.

Comment: I would agree with you, but I am running Yosemite, which meant that I had to continuously read posts until I found this one - http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite-development-server/ along with another post http://akrabat.com/php/setting-up-php-mysql-on-os-x-yosemite/ and one more http://php-osx.liip.ch (this made everything work)